# Cycle for error

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have one problem with my cycle for.
I parse data with JsonParser and after i use one cycle for print all data but i recive only the last result.

This is the code:

```
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Log.d("id_Persons", "id: " + json_data.getString("id_Persons") 
            + ", nome: " + json_data.getString("name") 
            + json_data.getString("address")
        );

        stringaFinale =  json_data.getString("id_Persons") + " " 
            + json_data.getString("name") + " " 
            + json_data.getString("address");
    }
    return stringaFinale;
}
catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

but, with

```
Log.d("id_Persons", "id: " + json_data.getString("id_Persons") 
    + ", nome: " + json_data.getString("name") 
    + json_data.getString("address")
);
```

I do not understand what is the error.
[This is the screen of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVi4J.png)

Comment: its because your are returning stringaFinale after for loop ends

Comment: Well, you're reassigning `stringaFinale` in every iteration of the loop, ignoring the previous value... how did you expect to get data for more than one value?

Comment: do string concatenation like stringaFinale = stringaFinale  + json_data.getString("id_Persons") + " " + json_data.getString("name") + " " + json_data.getString("address");

Comment: @JonSkeet  how to fix this error ?

Comment: Well we can't really tell what you're trying to do with `stringaFinale`... but you might want to use a `StringBuilder` to build up a final result...

Comment: Please give us example input and expected output (edit the question and add it there)

Comment: Since strings are immutable, use StringBuilder, to append new data and then return the end result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting its value in each iteration of `for` loop.

Change

```
 stringaFinale =  json_data.getString("id_Persons") + " " + json_data.getString("name") + " " + json_data.getString("address");
```

to

```
 stringaFinale +=  json_data.getString("id_Persons") + " " + json_data.getString("name") + " " + json_data.getString("address");
```

**Note:** You should initialize `stringaFinale` with empty string like this

```
String stringaFinale = "";
```

**Update:** Another nicer way is to use `StringBuilder` like this

```
// declare it before the loop 
StringBuilder stringaFinale = new StringBuilder(200); // use appropriate size

//Inside the loop
stringaFinale.append(json_data.getString("id_Persons") + " " + json_data.getString("name") + " " + json_data.getString("address"));

//Get the value
stringFinale.toString();
```

Comment: @Python_96: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Or rather use a StringBuilder in this case

Comment: @Rohit5k2: Yes yes :) don't worry ^_^